# Using parameters for HTML files.

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I have an HTML file with some charts ( JavaScript ) and currently I have all the values for the x and y Axis as static string values. My objective is to make the HTML file read all the x and y values from a csv file.

What is the best way to go about this ?

Comment: Can you read data from json instead of csv?

Comment: I don't know how to - but if it helps to pass parameters to be used by my charts then I could learn how to use Json to pass parameters

Comment: You can pass parameters but can't get them without using any server side technology like php, asp, jsp;

Comment: Oh ok .. Let me check ..

Comment: just use ajax to load the csv file, parse it, and then use the values.